# Bound methods in typescript

Tags: python, typescript

In Python there is a common pattern that works as follows

```python
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    def increment_and_print(self, i):
        self._x = self._x + i
        print(self._x)

instance = MyClass()
bound_method = instance.increment_and_print
```

Here, `bound_method` is equivalent to a function `lambda i: instance.increment_and_print(i)`, i.e. it contains the instance object like in a closure.

Now I wonder with typescript has a similar shorthand notation, i.e.

```js
class MyClass {
  private _x : number;
  constructor() { this._x = 0; }
  incrementAndPrint(i: number) {
    self._x += i;
    console.log(self._x)
  }
}
```

Would you just use lambda functions to generate a closure like the "bound method" shorthand in Python? Or is there another way?

Comment: I think the solution is to use the `bind` method: `var instance = new MyClass(); var bound_method = instance.increment_and_print.bind(instance);`. (The syntax may be off slightly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this using bind - functions are first class in JavaScript so you can pass them around quite easily:

```
class MyClass {
    private _x: number = 0;

    incrementAndPrint(i: number) {
        this._x += i;
        console.log(this._x)
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass();

const incrementAndPrint = myClass.incrementAndPrint.bind(myClass);

incrementAndPrint(2);
incrementAndPrint(3);
```

You can also do it with an arrow-function:

```
const incrementAndPrint = (num: number) => myClass.incrementAndPrint(num);
```